# A question on Schwartz space on the integers

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

I have a question regarding Schwartz space on the integers. The definition (of the semi-norms which can generate such space) is given as follow: 
[image]

Can someone explain why we need a square on the norm of $m$, while in Schwartz space for real numbers, we do not impose the "squared"?

Thx!

Comment: No need for that square. You can define a family of seminorms without it and still obtain the same topology. It is probably used to simplify subsequent computations